# How to use $scope.$apply() on a function which return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a function in my controller which return true false and based on this i am updating my view but some time value not updating a view. Here is a code:

this is a controller scope function:

```
    $scope.isLow = function () {
     $log.info("value:"+ phoneState.getCurrentVolumeState());
     return phoneStateService.getCurrentVolumeState();
};
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="home-volume-warning-text" data-ng-show="isLow()">
 some text
 </div>
```

Can someone tell me how i can use $scope.$apply() here on function.

Comment: Do you get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) maybe?

Comment: No actually there is no error. it seems to be scope is not updating itself so that view not getting a problem updated value. Mostly with this problem i have to use $scope.apply() for the scope variable to update always after a change but now not getting an idea that how to use this on a function itseld

Comment: Also please explain and show the code of `phoneStateService.getCurrentVolumeState()` because you don't use the `ngShow` directive correctly (Binding a function is terrible for performances)

Comment: Ahh i see this what you are saying. let me try to change phoneStateService.